# Rust problem with Vector of Generic structs

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a generic HTTP Server, but i'm having a problem to keep the routes in a Vec.

```
pub struct Route<T>
where
    T: Clone + IntoResponse,
{
    pub method: Method,
    pub path: String,
    pub func: fn() -> T,
}

impl<T> Route<T>
where
    T: Clone + IntoResponse,
{
    fn new(method: Method, path: String, func: fn() -> T) -> Self {
        Self { method, path, func }
    }
}

impl<T> AnyRoute for Route<T>
where
    T: Clone + IntoResponse,
{
    fn get_path(&self) -> String {
        self.path
    }

    fn get_method(&self) -> Method {
        self.method
    }
}

trait AnyRoute {
    fn get_path(&self) -> String;
    fn get_method(&self) -> Method;
}

pub struct Routes {
    pub routes: Vec<Box<dyn AnyRoute>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum RouteError {
    AlreadyInUse,
    DoesNotExist,
    CouldNotProcess,
}

impl Routes {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { routes: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn add_route<T: Clone + IntoResponse>(
        &mut self,
        method: Method,
        path: String,
        func: fn() -> T,
    ) -> Result<(), RouteError> {
        let route = Route::new(method, path, func);

        if let Some(_) = self
            .routes
            .iter()
            .find(|r| r.get_path() == route.path && r.get_method() == route.method)
        {
            Err(RouteError::AlreadyInUse)
        } else {
            self.routes.push(Box::new(route));
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    pub fn process_request(
        &self,
        stream: &mut TcpStream,
        path: String,
        method: &str,
    ) -> Result<(), RouteError> {
        let method: Method = Method::from(method);

        if let Some(route) = self
            .routes
            .iter()
            .find(|r| r.get_path() == path && r.get_method() == method)
        {
            let res = (route.func)();
            let str: String = (res).into_response().into();
            stream.write_all(str.as_bytes()).unwrap();
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(RouteError::DoesNotExist)
        }
    }

    pub fn handle(&self, stream: &mut TcpStream) {
        let mut buf = [0; 100];
        stream.read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();

        let string_buf = String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap();

        let mut tokens = string_buf.split(" ");

        let method = tokens.next().unwrap();
        let path = tokens.next().unwrap().to_string();

        match self.process_request(stream, path, method) {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(_) => {
                let res = Response::new(StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, "");
                let str: String = res.into();
                stream.write_all(str.as_bytes()).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
 error[E0609]: no field `func` on type `&dyn AnyRoute`
       --> src/http/routes.rs:108:30
        |
    108 |             let res = (route.func)();
        |                              ^^^^
```

I don't know how to store my `Routes`. I tried a lot of things to fix this, but I can't think of a way to make this compiled. I tried to box them, to create a trait, to make functions that return `impl IntoResponse`, and nothing fixed it.

Comment: What framework do you use? Please add all required imports.

Comment: Also, please make a **minimal** example.

Answer (score 2):

Just as you exposed `path` and `method` via getters, you need to expose `func` too.

```rust
trait AnyRoute {
    fn get_path(&self) -> String;
    fn get_method(&self) -> Method;
    fn execute(&self) -> Response;
}

impl<T> AnyRoute for Route<T>
where
    T: Clone + IntoResponse,
{
    // ...

    fn execute(&self) -> Response {
        (self.func)().into_response()
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- [In Rust, the convention is to call getters `field_name`, not `get_field_name`](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#getter-names-follow-rust-convention-c-getter).
- Your code will be more general if you will allow capturing closures in routes, i.e. take `impl Fn() -> T` instead of `fn() -> T` (and store `Box<dyn Fn() -> T>`).